# Trouble with NSTextField in Swift using xcode 6.1 (OSX)

Tags: xcode, macos, swift, nstextfield

I started Swift but not Objective C. Can someone teach me how to get and set the `NSTextField` in Swift using xcode 6.1 under OSX?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get and set the value of an `NSTextField` with the `stringValue` property.  For instance, if you have this `@IBOutlet` in your app:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textfield: NSTextField!
```

getting the value:

```
println("textfield is \(textfield.stringValue)")
```

setting the value:

```
textfield.stringValue = "this is my string"
```

Comment: thank you, its a bit difficult if you are a c# programmer before, programming for mac is a huge alteration